# Error "Expected Expression" in this template code

Tags: c++, templates

Why does this error appear and how do I fix it?

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  template<size_t N>
  void hello() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct bar {
  void world() {
    foo<T> f;
    f.hello<0>(); //Error: Expected expression
  }
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the `template` disambiguator, so the compiler will know that it shall parse `hello` as the name of a template member function, and the subsequent `<` and `>` as angular brackets delimiting the template arguments:

```
f.template hello<0>();
//^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ok that seems to work, but why is this needed? Why doesn't C++ just understand it like it was before? There is only one hello member template function there...

Comment: @7cows: Well, when parsing the template (so *before* you are actually instantiating the template with one specific `T`), the compiler does not know what the definition of `foo<T>` really looks like. It could have a data member called `hello` of type (say) `int` (in which case `f.hello<0> ...` could be `(f.hello < 0) > ...`), or a member function called `hello`, depending on `T`.

Comment: @7cows: Yes, there is a `hello` template, but `foo` may be specialized for some `T`, and the definition of the specialized `foo<T>` may look completely different from the primary template (e.g. it could have a `hello` data member of type `int` instead of a `hello` member function template

Comment: Winning.  Thank you for this